# how to load dpdmp files into oracle through command prompt

Tags: oracle, impdp, dmp

I have a dpdmp file which I have to load into oracle database

I've tried these formats:

```
impdp system/tiger@oratest FILE=WB_PROD_FULL_20MAY11.dmp 

imp <username>/<password>@<hostname> file=<filename>.dmp log=<filename>.log full=y; 

impdp <username>/<password> directory=<directoryname> dumpfile=<filename>.dmp logfile=<filename>.log full=y; 

IMP SYSTEM/systempassword@ORA_alias FILE=user.DMP FROMUSER=user TOUSER=user GRANTS=Y log =user.log 

imp userid=system/manager file=my_dump.dmp full=y log=imp.log
```

None of these worked.

Comment: imp won't work, you'll need to use impdp

Comment: you can find examples here in the docs https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#i1009093

Comment: if you want help, show us the errors you get after doing your impdp command